# How to set default values on a multi select for react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, dropdown, multi-select

I am using the react-native-dropdown-select-list package to create a multi-select dropdown.  Having a hard time with setting pre-filled default values.  Using pre-filled default values for an edit form page where I want the current selected options to be prefilled.

I looked up the repo for react-native-dropdown-select-list and doesnt seem like the defaultOption prop that is used to store default values is available for the MultiSelect even though it is available for the Single Select dropdown.  Would anyone know of a work around to set pre-fill default values?  Or would I have to create my own multi select dropdown from scratch?

The defaultOption here works:

```
import {
  MultipleSelectList,
  SelectList,
} from "react-native-dropdown-select-list";

<SelectList
  onSelect={() => alert('selected')}
  setSelected={(setSelected => console.log(setSelected))}
  data={options}
  defaultOption={{ value: "Jammu & Kashmir", key: "1", }} //default selected option
/>
```

This does not work:

```
import {
  MultipleSelectList,
  SelectList,
} from "react-native-dropdown-select-list";

<MultipleSelectList
  onSelect={() => alert('selected')}
  setSelected={(setSelected => console.log(setSelected))}
  data={options}
  defaultOption={{ value: "Jammu & Kashmir", key: "1", }} //default selected option
/>
```

Ive tried passing in the defaultOption prop to MultipleSelectList, Ive also tried other libraries but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

The code that performs this action of showing the default value is missing. You can add the snippet below along with the other Effects present in the component's internal code.

Add this inside the component code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
      if (!_firstRender && defaultOption && oldOption.current != defaultOption.key){
        oldOption.current = defaultOption.key
        setSelected(defaultOption.key);
        setSelectedVal(defaultOption.value);
      }
      if (defaultOption && _firstRender && defaultOption.key != undefined){
        oldOption.current = defaultOption.key
        setSelected(defaultOption.key);
        setSelectedVal(defaultOption.value);
      }
}, [defaultOption])
```

Comment: hello, please could you translate your post to English?